# list insertion in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Suppose  I have two lists as follows:-

```
a = [9,11,12,13] b = [0,5]
```

Now, I want to create another list in which if the index equals to any element of b,then I want to insert -1 at that particular index
so in the above case if index = 0,5
the new list will contain `[-1,9,11,12,13,-1]`
How to do this, if the two lists are given above as input to a function?

Comment: Cant understand. at index 0 in `a` there is 9. So you want to replace the 9 to -1? But your expected output is different.

Comment: What did you try, to solve your problem? code?

Comment: Basically I want to do the following :- for index in max(b,len(a)) if index in b newlist[index] = -1 else newlist[index] = a[count] count +=1 but in a more pythonic way

Comment: count starts from 0 obviously

Comment: I think you should organize better your question. Maybe give a working example of what you accomplished til now so we can compare with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question I believe that's what you're looking for.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [0, 3]

def insert_at_indexes(li, indexes, value):
    for ind in indexes:
        li.insert(ind, value)

insert_at_indexes(a,b,-1)
```

Comment: Yes , but it produces an error for the index let's say 6 in the above case.

Comment: That can easily be special-cased. For example, what do you want to happen with b = [0, 7] in the above case?

Comment: I want to insert -1 in that case . But I am actually looking out for a one liner solution. Something that uses map or lambda.